# Access extended class method

Tags: java, bluej

I have a class called `Occupant` and `extended Occupant classes` for **different occupant types** such as **Animal, Food, Tools, Treasure**.

All occupants are placed on `GridSquares`, A Square can hold up to **3 occupants**.

Occupant class has a **method** to **get all the Occupants on a GridSqure** when the position is given. 
The method will return a **Occupant Array** with extended occupant classes.( E.G: An Animal, A Tool and A Food).

```
   Occupant[] allOccupants = newGridSquare.getOccupants();

    for ( Occupant oneOccupant : allOccupants)
      {
         if(oneOccupant.getStringRepresentation() == "A")
         {

             player.reduceStamina(oneOccupant.getDanger());

         }
     }
```

compiler cannot access `getDanger` method in Animal class just because I already have assigned it as Occupant.

How can I access getDanger method in extended Occupant class **Animal**?

Comment: Related: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Your question is unclear; are you saying that only `Animal` has a `getDanger` method, and `Occupant` doesn't? Please post the code for the classes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thats another problem :)

Comment: Also, are you trying to use `stringRepresentation` to indicate the class of the `Occupant`? There are much cleaner and safer ways to do that in Java; `instanceof` is generally best, and an `enum` is far better than the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the instance

```
for ( Occupant oneOccupant : allOccupants)
{
    if("A".equals(oneOccupant.getStringRepresentation()))
    {
        Animal animal = (Animal) oneOccupant;
        player.reduceStamina(animal.getDanger());
    }
}
```

Assuming the `"A"` is an identifier for an `Animal` instance and Animal is a subclass of `Occupant` and has a `getDanger()` method. Otherwise, first do a check

```
if (oneOccupant instanceof Animal) {
     Animal animal = (Animal) oneOccupant;
     player.reduceStamina(animal.getDanger());
}
```

---

Related :

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As getDanger does not exists under Occupant class but in specific class Animal. So you you need to downcast oneOccupant  To Animal class .

Another solution is you declare getDanger under Occupant class and implement it under extended class. In case of classes except Animal, you can provide empty implementation. But thats not a good approach from design point of view but sometime is resorted to in case of legacy code